# Run-time error '1004' ShowDataForm method of Worksheet class failed

Tags: vba, excel

```
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
```

Returns Error 1004

I tried:

```
Range("B4:D4").Select
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
```

It didn't help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### When you use the ShowDataForm method, Microsoft Excel looks for the data list in two places:

- The defined name "Database." If a range has been defined as the database, Microsoft Excel will display the data form, and the data in that range will be accessible.
- Cells A1:B2 on the specified worksheet. Microsoft Excel will attempt to find a list whose upper-left corner lies in the range A1:B2. If a list is found, Microsoft Excel will display the data form and the data in the list will be accessible.

### WORKAROUND

1. Either place the Table in A1:B2 Range.
2. Or Name the Range Database, Ex:

   ```
   Range("B5").CurrentRegion.Name = "database"
   ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
   ```

   worked for me
   [Source 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110462)
   [Source 2](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/excel-macro-runtime-error-1004.1034540/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are struggeling with this solution...
It seems the "database" Text is language based. Once i changed it to "datenbank" (german Excel) it worked. Dont know if this is the case for all localisations though.

Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I received runtime error 1004 on the ShowDataForm function until I physically moved the upper-left corner of the data table to cell A1. Macro did not work when the table was positioned anywhere else in the worksheet. Name of the table did not matter. Selecting a cell inside the table did not matter.