# Utilise ShowDataForm Excel but hide data

Tags: excel

I have attempted the solution previously posted 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31642837/6463950
but whilst this code works nicely it doesn't get round the issue of wanting to have the database hidden from the user view. Has anyone determined a way to do this?
I am using the following code. If I hide the worksheet or hide the columns on TimeCapture then I get a runtime error '1004'

```
Sub OrderEntry()
Sheets("TimeCapture").Select
Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Name = "database"
ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to select or active the sheet. You can even have the worksheet hidden.
**Use:**

> Sheets("TimeCapture").ShowDataForm